# jQuery "stacking" divs (like Lego)

Tags: jquery, html, css, lego-mindstorms

I've been working on something fun, stacking my divs like lego. I've been able to get it to stack once using appendTo and positioning, but if you click more than once the divs appear in an unexpected (to me) place!

You can see what I mean here: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Dk585/2/). (You can click the red div to remove the stacked divs)

Is there a way to make the divs stack exactly like the first one, "on top" of each other like a tower of legos?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lastPos = [-4, -3];
$('.cube, .cubeStack').click( function() {
    lastClicked = $('<div class="cubeStack"></div>')
       .css({top:lastPos[0], left:lastPos[1]})
       .appendTo($(this));

    lastPos[0] -= 1;
    lastPos[1] -= 1;
});
```

- Set `.cubeStack` position to absolute
- Decrement each time you add a new stack

http://jsfiddle.net/Dk585/8/

> P.S. I found it rather cute actually <3

Comment: Yes, this works in the way that it carries on the stack, thanks! But after you click the clear button, they continue stacking from the last position. :)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Edited my answer, fixed that :)

Comment: Aha, thanks very much, good solution. And glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

Far "stacking" the divs on top of each other use prependTo().
The difference is that appendTo() adds the element as last child and prependTo() add the element as first child to the element.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it had no effect on the outcome: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Dk585/7/